# Designer the ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity

I wanted to know if the [charmanderproject](http://charmanderproject.github.io/Themes/) could become part of ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has been confirmed. I doubt a design concept such as that one would be implemented. At the core, you could easily do something like this if you take the time and modify your system.

You could always stay in touch with the development of the project. A few days ago they announced a GitHub page for the project. Click [here](https://github.com/CharmanderProject/Themes)
for the project and how it is doing.

Comment: say you know if you have any preview of what will be the ubuntu 16.04? and when the snappy package will be ready? and if he will have integration or conversion between android packages for Ubuntu (snappy package)?